# Database is shown in emulator but not on my android device

Tags: android, sqlite, android-assets

Here is my code...

```
private static String DB_NAME = "pa1.db";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/in.bitcode.sn/databases/";
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

Comment: You cannot write to `/data` folder. It works in the emulator because in the emulator you're *[root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)*, while you're probably not in your device.

Comment: So wats the solution for this ?

Comment: Check my answer. Besides this, there's no solution but becoming root in your device.

Comment: is it nessasary for a package name that it should be start from only com.packagename ???

Comment: No, but that has nothing to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write to `/data` folder. This is an Android system folder. It works in the emulator because in the emulator you're *[root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser)*, while you're probably not in your device.

Maybe you want to use [Android's integrated backup API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) instead of this.

Comment: Is there any limit in storing string array in string.xml

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with your question. If you want to ask something else, make a new question.